# Is it possible to associate multiple, disjoint elements to pages in Pager.js?

Tags: knockout.js, single-page-application, pager, pagerjs

I'm building an application and am starting with Knockout.  We're to a point where we're going to need to implement paging, and it looks like the de-facto library for doing that in Knockout is Pager.js.

Pager is good and pretty easy to use, but there's a use case we have that I haven't been able to figure out a Pager solution for.

In many of our pages, we want to be able to show certain content in multiple, disjoint elements on the page.  (Don't know if "disjoint" would be the proper term; really meaning elements that are in no way connected, as in completely separate branches of the DOM tree.)  For instance, we may want to display certain things in our header, footer, or menu along with the main UI that Pager will render.

So far, it appears that Pager links a page to only one element, and that is the element that it shows/hides based on which page is active.

Is there a way to have Pager show/hide multiple elements that are disjoint?  Would I have to rely on something like callbacks to get this done?  (I know that there are callbacks for when Pager shows/hides a page, and I think that those could be used to acheive this, but it would be better if Pager handled this for me.)

If Pager does not really support this use case, is there another similar library to try that is compatible with Knockout?  Or, even, would there be another alternative to Knockout completely that would support this (AngularJS, Ember, etc)?

EDIT:  Looking at Ember, kind of what I am looking for is what is [described here and their "outlets" features](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/) (the last example on the page).  So, would be looking for somewhat similar functionality with Knockout.  I do think I could use some of the Knockout callbacks to mimic this, but it would probably involve a lot of jQuery to move things around or hide/show things.  I'd rather not have to do that as it would become more of a maintenance headache as time goes and the application gets bigger.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and it is very easy to achieve. Read http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html

Basically, you only have to use `$parent`, `$parents[x]` or, ultimately, `$root` to access observables that are not at the level of the object you're using as the context.

Here is an example (using pager.js or not does not change the way it works) :

```
var viewModel = {
  user: {
    id: ko.observable(1),
    name: ko.observable('John')
  }
  menu: {
    links: {
      about: 'about.html',
      index: 'index.html'
    }
  }
};
```

WIth this HTML :

```
<div id="header">
  <p>Your name is <span data-bind="text: user.name"></span></p>
</div>
<div id="menu" data-bind="with: menu">
  <p>Your name is still <span data-bind="text: $parent.user.name"></span></p>
  <p>Your name is still <span data-bind="text: $parents[0].user.name"></span></p>
  <p>Your name is still <span data-bind="text: $root.user.name"></span></p>
</div>
```